# if $w=e^{\pi z}$ find all values of $|z|=r$ for which $w=i$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Question(s) below:**
>
> $(1)$. if $w=e^{\pi z}$ find all values of $|z|=r$ for which $w=i$
>
> $(2)$. Without finding the equation of the curve obtained from transforming $|z|=r=constant$, what are the values of $r$ for which the transformed curve will:
>
> > $a)$ not encircle the point $w=i$
> >
> > $b)$ will have a cusp
> >
> > $c)$ will encircle the point $w=i$ exactly twice.

My attempt:

$(1). e^{\pi z}=i=e^{i\pi /2}$

$$ \pi z = i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$$

$$ z = i(\frac{1}{2}+2k)$$

$$\therefore |z| = \frac{1}{2}+2k$$

$(2)a.$ I think all values that are not in $|z|=\frac{1}{2}+2k \space \therefore |z|<\frac{1}{2}$

$(2)b.$ I think for all values $\frac{dw}{dz}=0$, however given that $w=e^{\pi z}\space $, $\frac{dw}{dz}\ne 0$ therefore there are no cusps.

$(3)c.$no idea about this one, please assist

Someone please check if what i'm doing makes sense and please assist with $c$ -Thanks.

Comment: Many many mistakes here. First you can't just take the logarithm of a complex number without taking some precautions, so I would advise not to do it. You should start by writing $i = e^{it}$ (which $t$ ?) then simplify your equation to something like $e^{iw}=0$ that you can hopefully solve.

Comment: do you mean that in $e^{\pi z} = w$ @ $w=i$ i should do the following:

$w=e^{\pi z} = e^{i 2k\pi} = i$

$\therefore ln(w) = \pi z = 2k\pi i$ such that $z=2ki$

Comment: Don't take the log !! And your $y$ st $i=e^{i y}$ is wrong (or so it seems on my small phone screen)

Comment: Rather than take a log, divide LHS by RHS (or the opposite) in your equation (you can do it because your exp is never nil) and use the fact that we know the general solution to $e^x=1$ is $x=...$

Comment: Btw $|z|$ is always (by definition) a real positive number, so you should have spotted that your solution was problematic

Comment: @AlexH. can you please hint me on how i can answer $(c)$, btw i have edited the post to what i think you were getting at -Thanks.